# Why are there so few open source GWT apps?

Tags: java, open-source, gwt

Something I have found strange since I started working on GWT is how few open source projects there are in this technology.

Initially I was surprised to discover this mainly because GWT itself is open source. But after puzzling over this, my suspicion is that it is mainly used for internal projects by large corporations who already use Java and are using GWT for their RIAs instead of Flex or Rails. My understanding is that large corporations that use Java would tend to have lower contributions to open source because their focus is mainly on internal or commercial applications.

Does this sound like an accurate interpretation or does anyone have a different explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: we used gwt in our school project in study. i didn't fell in love with it... it promises easy development with zero javascript and so on... but in the end, you still have to apply .css hacks and javascript injections... i think if i could restart the project, i would have just written the stuff myself, with some javascript framework. not to mention the hairy weird resize behavior... and how it didn't work most of the time unless one experimented hours of times...

Comment: I thought you could get away with not doing any hacks by limiting your requirements to those of the technology - many technologists hate to do that but that's what I would do - say no to js & css hacks and just say "sorry - we can't do x in GWT but we can do y instead".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It actually seems quite reasonable to me that corporations, particularly those who use closed source, would favor GWT more than open-source developers, for exactly the reasons related to those mentioned in the question:

- They already use Java, and in particular have experienced Java developers
- There is a perceived (and sometimes real) higher cost in supporting multiple languages
- Management is reluctant to add either another bullet point on job postings (must know Javascript) or send developers to training

Open-source developers, on the other hand, are often hobbyists (though not always), and hobbyists tend to be more interested in picking up new technologies "for the fun of it."  Thus a hobbyist would be more open to writing Javascript directly, probably with the aid of a Javascript framework that doesn't involve translating from some other source language.

Specifically concerning source language translation, it's a [leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).  Eventually you're probably going to want to drop down into "raw" Javascript, and it's easier to do in an environment where you're already writing JS than one in which you're writing Java that gets translated.

Comment: I agree with your points about hobbyists. And perhaps another factor is that Java can be kind of a dirty word among hobbyist programmers who see it as a language for 'suits'.

Comment: GWT makes it so difficult to drop down into raw Javascript and make changes (because of the optimizations that have been made) that I find it easier to insist on not doing any hacks but instead limiting my requirements to those of the technology - many technologists hate to do this - i.e. just say no to js & css hacks and simply say "sorry - we can't do x in GWT but we have to do y instead because that's just how it is" :)

Comment: i dont think GWT makes it hard to drop down to javascript - it simply requires a JSNI call. 

Though, I have to say, the comment about hobbiests regarding java as for the 'suits' is probably correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, but you might want to add in a couple more factors:

GWT is fairly young

OpenSource programmers work in their language of choice, and for small 1-person projects, Java can be a little uncomfortable if you don't already know it (I'm the biggest Java fan around, but everything has it's limitations).

Java isn't really a great choice for web front-ends, so even though GWT is a great solution for that, it wouldn't ever be more attractive than rails to a very small development team.

Comment: Your point about Java not being popular for open souruce is not reflected in the numbers. There is a great deal of Java open source. But I agree that it's not an obvious choice for a front-end technology.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Personally I really like it, but it seems like everywhere I turn people are moving to Groovy or Scala or Ruby on Rails.  I just don't think Java is considered Fun and Hip.  Of course, my personal belief is that when working with a large group, the last thing I'd look for in a language is fun!

Comment: I dont think gwt can be considered young still - its been around for like 2 years at least. 

I think the uptake being slow in the opensource community is because the 'front end' people tend to like raw js and css+html, instead of the componentization concept favoured by most desktop UI coders. and gwt targets the latter, but they are a rarer breed on the interwebs.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because GWT leverages javascript and [Richard Stallman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Stallman) [isn't a fan](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/javascript-trap.html).

Comment: That's funny, but I think he is probably the only FOSS advocate who believes that...

Comment: I don't get the feeling that Richard Stallman is holding back the tide of GWT open source.

Comment: I don't think so either, but he brings up a few good points.

Comment: Indeed. It's an argument I hadn't thought about. Very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've avoided GWT for projects I want to open source because I've found it tricky to use it for Test Driven Development in Eclipse. I wouldn't do open source any other way these days.

There must be ways to get it working, but it resisted all my attempts, so I just switched to a different technology.